What are the size of screws for an M.2 NVMe install on a Gigabyte Z690 UD DDR4 motherboard?
Starting upgrade of a build with a Gigabyte Z690 UD DDR4 motherboard I purchased some M.2 screws just to find the thread is the wrong size (M2).
What is the thread size for M.2 NVMe installation at the Gigabyte Z690 board?
I'd assume M3 as the M2 just drops in?
 
There is nothing obvious in the manual:

https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z690-gx-series_c_1002_v1.pdf


I have searched high and low and also rechecked the manual, added som more information and a link to the manaul at Gigabyte

I haven't found any official Gigabyte documentation, but the Crucial About M.2 SSD screws contains:

M.2 Screw sizes are not standardized in all systems so if the screw that is included with your Crucial SSD does not fit into the standoff in your PC you will need to contact the system or motherboard manufacturer to find out the correct sizes needed.

Searching found items such as M.2 SSD Mounting Screws Kit for ASUS, Gigabyte, MSI & ASRock Motherboards - 30 Pieces which contain amongst other items:

M2.0 * 2.5mm screw
M3.0 * 3mm screw

Therefore, for the Gigabyte Z690 I assume M3.0 * 3mm is the screw size to be used.

not standardized ... - thanks, not too nice to find on this of Christmas

M3 standoff and you have either M2 or M3 internal thread in the standoff
Not easy to come by in Denmark but easiest is Amazon, cheapest is probably TEMU or similar
I can find M3 in sets both places
